# Editing title to de-specify specific platform if question is platform specific to broaden possible answers?

Tags: discussion, title

Say I've got a question about how to do something, if I find the exact same question but specified to a software that I don't have access to, should I edit the original question so that the question is broader or do I duplicate the question this time specifying the software I want to use?

Comment: Please provide examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that you should post a new question.

If you edit an old question, which has an accepted answer, there would be less incentive for people to answer it. A fresh question gives you the power to mark a question as accepted, and lets other people gain reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Besides of Devdatta's point that you probably won't get many new answers to an old, accepted question, there's also the issue that someone had a very specific request (for good reasons or not) and I don't think it would be appropriate to just go there and remove the specifics.

As a general rule of thumb I'd recommend posting a new question - maybe linking the old one.